# Simulating LoadLibraryEx's LOAD_LIBRARY_SEARCH_SYSTEM32 functionality

Tags: windows, winapi, dll

Often one wants to `LoadLibrary` a system DLL like `Kernel32.dll`, handily `LoadLibraryEx` has a `dwFlags` parameter that allows you to specify `LOAD_LIBRARY_SEARCH_SYSTEM32`.

For security reasons, this can be very important as malicious attackers can subvert the default search paths that `LoadLibrary` looks through.

However Windows XP, which I must still support, cannot use `LOAD_LIBRARY_SEARCH_SYSTEM32` as it didn't exist eons ago.  This leads me to the following conclusion: I need to come up with a fully qualified path and pass that to `LoadLibrary`.

However, a robust implementation of this is tricky due to WoW64 and file-system redirection.
I have to worry about this possibility because the code in question lives in a library and can be called in strange environments.

My current thoughts are something like the following pseudo-code:

```
string Path;
BOOL Wow64Process;
if (IsWow64Process(CurrentProcess(), &Wow64Process) && Wow64Process && 
    WoW64FSRedirectionIsDisabled)
    Path = GetSystemWow64Directory();
else
    Path = GetSystemDirectory();
Path += "\Kernel32.dll";
LoadLibrary(Path);
```

I have considered, and rejected using `Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection` and `Wow64RevertWow64FsRedirection` but this is problematic as it will leave FS redirection disabled in the library's `DLLMain`.

Given the above, what's the best way to go about what I am trying to do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In terms of loading a DLL without dependencies, you are over thinking this. If the user has disabled file system redirection in a WOW64 process then `LoadLibraryEx` will attempt to load the DLLs from the 64 bit system32 folder. So you can simply do exactly the same and remove all that WOW64 code.

However, the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684179.aspx) says (emphasis mine):

> If this value is used, %windows%\system32 is searched for the DLL **and its dependencies**.

So, your approach cannot replicate `LOAD_LIBRARY_SEARCH_SYSTEM32` because you can only supply the full path for the DLL you load, but not for its dependencies.

The only way to hope to replicate this is to force `system32` to be at the head of the DLL search path. Specifying a full path won't help you.

Finally, are you sure that `LOAD_LIBRARY_SEARCH_SYSTEM32` is not available on XP64?

Comment: I am sure that `LOAD_LIBRARY_SEARCH_SYSTEM32` is not supported on XP64. It is only supported from Windows Vista to before Windows 8 with [KB2533623](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2533623) while Windows 8 purportedly supports it _de novo_.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to the other answers use SetDlldirectory.
The advantage ist that the current Directory isn't checked for a DLL-load.

Still open is the search via PATH... but this is in the last Position, so your DLL located in the SYSTEM32 directoryies should be loaded first using SettDllDirectory.

Also it is supported since XP SP1

Comment: `SetDllDirectory` only has an effect on modules that are loaded *after* this API has been called. This generally limits applicability to delay-loaded modules or manually loaded modules. In other words, `SetDllDirectory` has no effect on where kernel32.dll is loaded from.

Comment: But this wasn't the question... ;) The question was about a "replacement" for explicit LoadLibrary calls and the flag LOAD_LIBRARY_SEARCH_SYSTEM32.

Comment: *"Often one wants to `LoadLibrary` a system DLL like Kernel32.dll"*

Comment: If you use SetDllDirectory, usually no "foreign" KERNEL32.DLL is loaded, because the "problematic "Current Directory" is no longer in the search path! DLL-planting/hijacking via the PATH variable will not work, if KERNEL32 is already in the memory. And for 99,9% for all application this is the case. Correct me if I am wrong.